# Keras multiple output expected shape and got shape

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am try to train a model which detect 128d vector to recognize face. Input of model is an image and output is 128d vector (regression) which get from "face_recognition" library.

When I put 128 output to train I got this error:

`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (128,)`

But when I try only one output, fit function works. 
The strange part of that prediction shape is (1, 128) but I can't give 128 output to train.

Here is my model:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
import keras
def build_facereg_disc():
  # load model
  model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(64, 64, 3))
  # add new classifier layers
  flat1 = Flatten()(model.outputs)
  class1 = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(flat1)
  output = Dense(128, activation='relu')(class1)
  # define new model
  model = models.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=output)
  # summarize
  return model

facereg_disc = build_facereg_disc()
facereg_disc.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),  # Optimizer
              # Loss function to minimize
              loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              # List of metrics to monitor
              metrics=['binary_crossentropy'])
```

And summary:

```
Model: "model_27"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_20 (InputLayer)        (None, 64, 64, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 64)        1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 8, 8, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 4, 4, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 2, 2, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_10 (Flatten)         (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 2048)              4196352   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 128)               262272    
=================================================================
Total params: 19,173,312
Trainable params: 19,173,312
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is preprocessing:

```
dir_data      = "data_faces/img_align_celeba/"
Ntrain        = 2000 
Ntest         = 100
nm_imgs       = np.sort(os.listdir(dir_data))
## name of the jpg files for training set
nm_imgs_train = nm_imgs[:Ntrain]
## name of the jpg files for the testing data
nm_imgs_test  = nm_imgs[Ntrain:Ntrain + Ntest]
img_shape     = (64, 64, 3)

def get_npdata(nm_imgs_train):
    X_train = []
    for i, myid in enumerate(nm_imgs_train):
        image = load_img(dir_data + "/" + myid,
                         target_size=img_shape[:2])
        image = img_to_array(image)/255.0
        X_train.append(image)
    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    return(X_train)

X_train = get_npdata(nm_imgs_train)
```

```
X_train.shape = (2000, 64, 64, 3)
y_train.shape = (2000, 128)
```

I use batch size like:

```
idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], half_batch)
            imgs = X_train[idx]

            labels = y_train[idx]

            reg_d_loss_real = facereg_disc.train_on_batch(imgs, labels)
```

Comment: The error you are getting tells you that your dataset has outputs of dimension 1, not 128 as you are expecting. Can you show a sample of output data to confim?

Comment: Can you show the shape of actual outputs and the shape of labels?

Comment: I try  with `prediction = facereg_disc.predict(np.array([X_train[0]]))
print(prediction.shape)` and shape is **(1, 128)** @ThomasSchillaci @pntehan

Comment: Are your input samples of shape `(1, 64, 64, 3)`?

Comment: Yes, also I can fit with `facereg_disc.fit(X_train[0].reshape(1,64,64,3), [1])` but it must be 128 output not only 1. @ThomasSchillaci

Comment: Could you parse your data preparation code up to the fit method? That would make things easier to debug

Comment: I added preprocessing parts to question. Actually, I use batch but it doesn't work with only one sample. @ThomasSchillaci

Comment: How do you get your `y_train`? Also, I assume that when you write `X_train.shape = (2000, 64, 64, 3)` and `y_train.shape = (2000, 128)`, it's you telling us the shapes of those arrays (from print(X_train.shape) for instance)

Comment: Yes, these are output of print shape. I extract 128d vector with face recognition library and append a list. Then I converted to np array. I have a (2000, 128) y_train @ThomasSchillaci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from your loss function. As explained in the [doc](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparse_categorical_crossentropy-function), `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` expects each sample in `y_true` to be an integer encoding the class, whereas `CategoricalCrossentropy` expects a one-hot encoded representation (which is your case).

So, switch to `CategoricalCrossentropy` and you should be fine.

However, to reproduce, I had to change:

```py
flat1 = Flatten()(model.outputs)
```

To:

```py
flat1 = Flatten()(model.outputs[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my y_true is not one-hot encoded. It is float number between -1 and 1. Isn't there a problem?

Comment: Yes there is a problem, using a categorical loss expects your outputs to represent categories, what does your output represent?

Comment: My output is 128 floating point which between -1 and 1. Ex: 0.32. So, it is a multi output regression problem. Which loss function can I do?

Comment: It looks good. I tried mean squared error before but `model.outputs[0]` solved the problem.